# What do angled single quotes do?

Tags: php

I've modified some code, pasted from elsewhere to suit my needs, but i stumbled upon these weird single quotes, and their output surprised me a lot

```
$test = `nslookup google.com`;
echo $test;
```

This actually performs an `nslookup`, without running doing anything but defining the variable, how is this possible?

Comment: See also [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called "Execution Operators", and they are actually *not* single quotes, but `backticks`.

You can read more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: "backticks", not "backsticks" =)

Comment: I actually kinda like "backsticks"